# deleting an object in django

Tags: python, html, django

i want to delete a task from the database so i use this code
this is my delete view

```
def task_Delete(request,id=None):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = TaskForm()
            id = int(request.POST.get('task.id'))
            task = Task.objects.get(id=id)
            task.delete()
            messages.success(request,"successfully delete")
            return render_to_response('home.html', {'form': form})
```

and that is my urls.py

```
url(r'^task_Delete/$', views.task_Delete, name='task_Delete')
```

this the code of the button delete :

```
<form action="{% url 'task_Delete' %}" method="post" >
               {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="task_id" value="{{task.id}}" />
               <input type="submit" value="delete task">
        </form></td>
  </tr>
```

when i click on delete nothing happend i don't know why , please help thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are various problems in your code (for example the `TaskForm` is not needed at all) however if you change the line

`id = int(request.POST.get('task.id'))`

to

`id = int(request.POST.get('task_id'))`

the object will probably be deleted; remember that the request parameter's name will be the same as the `name` of the input (`task_id`). I recommend using proper CBVs (a `DeleteView`) for what you want to do - if you want a slow and comprehensive tutorial on that I recommend this article: https://spapas.github.io/2018/03/19/comprehensive-django-cbv-guide/

Comment: thank's for answering  , my new views.py is                                  class taskDelete(DeleteView):
 model = task
 success_url = reverse_lazy('home')                                                and urls.py                                                                         
 url(r'^home/?<task_id>[0-9]+/$', views.MyDeleteView.as_view(), name='task_Delete'),                                                                         still nothing happend

Comment: How are you calling your delete view? You must use ``{% url "task_Delete" task.id %}`` to set the form action (and not use the hidden task_id field as before)